# Setting up SVN Server in CentOS

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn, centos

I'm trying to setup a SVN repository on a Linux (CentOS) server.

I installed svn, created a group for svn and added users. 
I also gave permissions to the group.

However, I'm not able to checkout from outside the server (i.e. on a windows machine using tortoise). I keep getting:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'svn+ssh://user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/project'
Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

However if I run the checkout command inside the server using the same Username/Password it works.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I access my svn server from linux, then yes, ssh. But from Windows with tortoise, I access the svn server by https (combined with TRAC) which seems easier as you don't have to set up a ssh agent with Putty (eg Pageant) in order to enable your ssh access from your windows machine to your svn server. See [this link](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html). I guess this is what your are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you SSH from the Windows machine to the server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the same username and password?  If not, that could be your problem.